# Error The sourceLayer parameter must be provided for vector source types

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

mapbox GL:  I got this error

Error: The sourceLayer parameter must be provided for vector source types.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If the layer-source type = geojson,  the map.setFeatureState needs source, id,

if the layer-source type= vector(for example tilesets URL),
the map.setFeatureState needs source, id, and for vector sources sourceLayer properties.

sample vector source :

```js
//var _mapbox_style = 'mapbox://styles/hoogw/cjusyfrn725qp1flhynv414z1';
var _mapbox_tileset = "mapbox://hoogw.77wjwdb4";

var _layer_name = "countries-1ay4zz";

map.addSource("_geojson_source", {
  type: "vector",
  url: _mapbox_tileset,
});

map.addLayer({
  id: ___id,

  type: "fill",
  //'type': 'line',

  source: "_geojson_source",

  // for vector-sourced-layer,here, must have "source-layer"
  // but for geojson-sourced-layer, no need "source-layer"
  "source-layer": _layer_name,
  layout: {},
  paint: {
    "fill-color": [
      "case",
      ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
      __stroke_color_highlight, // when hover   //"#FF0000",  // red
      __stroke_color, // when normal//  "#FFFF00" // yellow
    ],

    "fill-opacity": [
      "case",
      ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
      0.7, // when hover
      0, // when normal
    ],
  }, // paint
});

//=====================  end ========= add tileset layer =================================

// --------- line ---------------

map.on("mousemove", ___id, function (e) {
  if (e.features.length > 0) {
    if (hoveredFeatureId) {
      map.setFeatureState(
        {
          source: "_geojson_source",
          sourceLayer: _layer_name,
          id: hoveredFeatureId,
        },
        { hover: false }
      );
    }

    if (e.features[0].id) {
      // have feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)
      hoveredFeatureId = e.features[0].id;

      map.setFeatureState(
        {
          source: "_geojson_source",
          sourceLayer: _layer_name,
          id: hoveredFeatureId,
        },
        { hover: true }
      );
    } else {
      // missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field.
      // hover effect will failed.
      console.log(
        "missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field."
      );
      console.log(
        "hover effect will failed. feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)"
      );
    }

    //console.log('hoveredFeatureId = ',hoveredFeatureId)

    //********* show event.feature.properties  *********
    //console.log('e.features[0].properties #### ', e.features[0].properties)
    var _highlight_feature_properties = e.features[0].properties;
    show_info_outline_Tab(_highlight_feature_properties);

    //********* show event.feature.properties  *********
  } // if
}); // mousemove

map.on("mouseleave", ___id, function () {
  if (hoveredFeatureId) {
    map.setFeatureState(
      {
        source: "_geojson_source",
        sourceLayer: _layer_name,
        id: hoveredFeatureId,
      },
      { hover: false }
    );
  }
  hoveredFeatureId = null;

  empty_info_outline_Tab();
});

map.on("click", ___id, function (e) {
  //console.log('clicked')

  instance_tabs.select("list"); // open up locked tab

  if (e.features.length > 0) {
    if (clickedFeatureId) {
      map.setFeatureState(
        {
          source: "_geojson_source",
          sourceLayer: _layer_name,
          id: clickedFeatureId,
        },
        { click: false }
      );
    }

    if (e.features[0].id) {
      // have feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)
      clickedFeatureId = e.features[0].id;

      map.setFeatureState(
        {
          source: "_geojson_source",
          sourceLayer: _layer_name,
          id: clickedFeatureId,
        },
        { click: true }
      );
    } else {
      // missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field.
      // hover effect will failed.
      console.log(
        "missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field."
      );
      console.log(
        "hover effect will failed. feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)"
      );
    } // else

    //console.log('hoveredFeatureId = ',hoveredFeatureId)

    //********* show event.feature.properties  *********
    //console.log('e.features[0].properties #### ', e.features[0].properties)
    var _highlight_feature_properties = e.features[0].properties;
    //show_info_outline_Tab(_highlight_feature_properties)  // mouse over hover event
    show_listTab(_highlight_feature_properties); // click event
    //********* show event.feature.properties  *********
  } // if
}); // click
```

Answer (score 0):

geojson source sample:

```
         map.addSource("_geojson_source", {
          "type": "geojson",
          "data": ___GeoJson
          });



        if ((geojson_feature_type.toLowerCase() == 'polygon') 
         || (geojson_feature_type.toLowerCase() == 'multipolygon'))
        {


           //  ------------- polygon   -----------------------


              map.addLayer({
                  "id": "polygon-fills",
                  "type": "fill",
                  "source": "_geojson_source",
                  "layout": {},
                  "paint": {
                            "fill-color": [
                                              /*
                                                'case', ['<', ['to-number', ['get', 'Rank2019']],  16 ], '#FFFFFF',   // white

                                                        ['>', ['to-number', ['get', 'Rank2019']],  161 ], '#000000',  // black


                                                        // others
                                                        '#00FF00'

                                               */

                                              //https://materializecss.com/color.html

                                              "step",
                                                        ['to-number', ['get', 'Rank2019']],
                                                        '#FFFFFF',      // white
                                                        16,  '#e6ee9c',  // lime lighten-3
                                                        44,  '#009688',  //  teal
                                                        110, '#d84315', // deep-orange darken-3
                                                        162, '#000000'   // black





                                              ],





                            "fill-opacity": ["case",
                                                ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                                                0,
                                                0.7
                                            ]
                            }
                  });







              map.addLayer({
                  "id": "polygon-borders-line",
                  "type": "line",
                  "source": "_geojson_source",
                  "layout": {},
                  "paint": {
                                    "line-color": ["case",
                                               /*
                                                ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                                                 __stroke_color_highlight,  //"#FF0000",  // red
                                                 __stroke_color    //  "#FFFF00" // yellow
                                                */ 


                                                ["boolean", ["feature-state", "click"], false],
                                                __stroke_color_highlight_clicked,   // orange
                                                __stroke_color    //  "#FFFF00" // yellow

                                            ],

                                    "line-width": ["case",
                                              ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                                              5,
                                              1
                                          ]
                            }// paint
                  });



                  // When the user moves their mouse over the state-fill layer, we'll update the
                  // feature state for the feature under the mouse.
                  map.on("mousemove", "polygon-fills", function(e) {
                    if (e.features.length > 0) {

                          if (hoveredFeatureId) {
                                   map.setFeatureState({source: '_geojson_source', id: hoveredFeatureId}, { hover: false});
                                         }


                          //console.log('hover event e.features[0].id  >>>', e.features[0].id) 


                          if (e.features[0].id) {

                            // have feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID or default feature-array-index-id)
                            hoveredFeatureId = e.features[0].id;

                            map.setFeatureState({source: '_geojson_source', id: hoveredFeatureId}, { hover: true});


                          } else {

                            // missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field.
                            // hover effect will failed. 
                            console.log('missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field.')
                            console.log('hover effect will failed. feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)');
                          }

                          //console.log('hoveredFeatureId = ',hoveredFeatureId)



                                //********* show event.feature.properties  *********
                                  //console.log('e.features[0].properties #### ', e.features[0].properties)
                                  var _highlight_feature_properties = e.features[0].properties
                                  show_info_outline_Tab(_highlight_feature_properties)

                                //********* show event.feature.properties  *********


                     } // if
                  }); // mousemove




                  // When the mouse leaves the state-fill layer, update the feature state of the
                  // previously hovered feature.
                  map.on("mouseleave", "polygon-fills", function() {
                              if (hoveredFeatureId) {
                                              map.setFeatureState({source: '_geojson_source', id: hoveredFeatureId}, { hover: false});
                                              }
                              hoveredFeatureId =  null;



                              empty_info_outline_Tab()
                  });








                  map.on("click", "polygon-fills", function(e) {


                          //console.log('clicked')   

                          instance_tabs.select('list');   // open up locked tab


                          if (e.features.length > 0) 
                          {

                                if (clickedFeatureId) 
                                {
                                                    map.setFeatureState({source: '_geojson_source', id: clickedFeatureId}, { click: false});
                                }


                                if (e.features[0].id) 
                                {

                                  // have feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)
                                  clickedFeatureId = e.features[0].id;

                                  map.setFeatureState({source: '_geojson_source', id: clickedFeatureId}, { click: true});



                                } else {

                                  // missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field.
                                  // hover effect will failed. 
                                  console.log('missing feature.id, maybe because of feature properties - missing - ObjectID field.')
                                  console.log('hover effect will failed. feature.id ( converted from properties, OBJECTID)');




                                } // else 


                                //console.log('hoveredFeatureId = ',hoveredFeatureId)





                                //********* show event.feature.properties  *********
                                  //console.log('e.features[0].properties #### ', e.features[0].properties)
                                  var _highlight_feature_properties = e.features[0].properties
                                  //show_info_outline_Tab(_highlight_feature_properties)  // mouse over hover event
                                  show_listTab(_highlight_feature_properties)  // click event
                                //********* show event.feature.properties  *********




                          } // if
                        }); // click





               // ---- end ---- polygon ----
```